# Array of structures in C++:assignment of values to each structure in array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have declared a structure st below with a struct variable arr[], an array of structs.
Im trying to assign the value 1 to the 'num' variable, and values 1 to 10 to 'val' variable of the first 10 locations of array arr[]. And value 2 to 'num' and values 1 to 10 to 'val' of the next 10 locations. But when i traced the code, it won't assign values to the respective num and val of the same array location. If i wanted to assign num=1 and val=4 to the 4th structure it would assign num=1 to val of 3rd structure and val=4 to num of 4th structure.

My query is not about array indices.

The problem is:

If i wrote the statements

arr[2].num=1;
arr[2].val=2;

({num,val})

The expected result is: arr[2]={1,2}

But the actual result is: 
arr[1]={num,1}
arr[2]={2,val}

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>


class abc
{

 public:

 struct st
 {
  int num;
  int val;
 };

 st arr[21];

 void funct();

};

void abc::funct()
{
 int i,j,k=1;

 for(i=1;i<=2;i++)
 {
  for(j=1;j<=10;j++)
  {
   arr[k].num=i;
   arr[k].val=j;
   k++;
  }
 }

}


int main()
{
 abc z;

 z.funct();

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Arrays are 0 based, i.e. index starts with 0 and goes upto arraySize - 1 (from your declaration).
2) Walk through your code and look at what each line is doing...
3) Now think about what you need to do:
3.1) iterate over each element of the array
3.2) for each element access the structure
3.3) inside the structure you wanted to set
num = 1 to the **first** 10 elements and 2 to **second** 10 elements (do you see any simple mathematical rule here?)
val = arrayElementIndex (this is too simple)

Look at your code and think about how it needs to be done.

Comment: 1)doing k=1 assigns values to arr[0]. k=2 to arr[1] and so on
But still it assigns 'val' to num of the arr[k] and 'num' to previous structure.   This is happening:
If i wanted to assign the following {num,val} values to each structure: with k=1,
arr[0]={1,1
arr[1]={1,2}
arr[2]={1,3}
arr[3]={1,4}
 , 

It actually assigns the following values: 
arr[0]={1,1}
arr[1]={2,1}
arr[2]={3,1}
arr[3]={4,1}

2) at arr[0], 'num' gets assigned to 'val' of (-1)th structure and 'val' to 'num' of 0th structure.

I don't understand how this can happen.
Hope you've understood my query.

Comment: My query is not about array indices.

The problem is: 

If i wrote the statements 

arr[2].num=1;
arr[2].val=2;

({num,val})

The expected result is: arr[2]={1,2} 

But the actual result is: arr[1]={num,1}
arr[2]={2,val}

Comment: @user1460936 I just run the code as it should be (as I advised you to change it) and it works correctly. It does have the assignment of `arr[i].num = ?; arr[i].val = i;` and it produces correct result. Please re-write your code and post corrected version. Then we will be able to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: The code i've written is correct for the assignments i want to do i.e: 
arr[k].num=i; arr[k].val=j; But the output that it shows is incorrect. Plz run the code i've written. I've edited my question and shown what's the actual output and what I wanted.
@germann

Comment: the assignments that i want to make are very simple. im really surprised why it wouldn't make appropriate assignments.

Comment: @user1460936 If your code were correct it would have worked correctly. If it **does not** work correctly than you an assume that your code is **not** correct.  1) There is NO output code. 2) What does that `({num,val})` mean?

Comment: {num,val} are the values assigned to num and val of that structure.

I just now saw that the code works correctly if i declared the structure outside the class. The code i have written is correct. I don't know for what reason it doesn't work if i declared the struct inside the class. What could be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

If you want to access the first element in the array named `arr` then you do it by `arr[0]`.

So it will probably help if you do this:

> int i,j,k=0;

Comment: The poster explicitly stated that they want to assign positions 1-20. Why they skip 0, I have no idea.

Comment: 1)doing k=1 assigns values to arr[0]. k=2 to arr[1] and so on
But still it assigns 'val' to num of the arr[k] and 'num' to previous structure.   This is happening:
If i wanted to assign the following {num,val} values to each structure: with k=1,
arr[0]={1,1
arr[1]={1,2}
arr[2]={1,3}
arr[3]={1,4}
 , 

It actually assigns the following values: 
arr[0]={1,1}
arr[1]={2,1}
arr[2]={3,1}
arr[3]={4,1}

2) at arr[0], 'num' gets assigned to 'val' of (-1)th structure and 'val' to 'num' of 0th structure.

I don't understand how this can happen.

Comment: My query is not about array indices.

The problem is: 

If i wrote the statements arr[2].num=1;
arr[2].val=2;

The expected result is: arr[2]={1,2} ({num,val})

But the actual result is: arr[1]={num,1}
arr[2]={2,val}